# How do I get all the rows from the table SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

Hey guys I've been trying to work on an android project for my college but I am stuck at this point. I want to fetch all the rows from the table `students`, populate them into the `ArrayList` and then use `ListView` or `CardView` to display each student's record. This is the code I'm using:

```
public ArrayList<String> getStudentsEntry()
    {

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = db.query("STUDENT", ALL_COLUMN_NAME, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
        {
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
            String enrollment = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ENROLLMENT"));
            String year = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("YEAR"));
            String dob = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DOB"));
            String email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("EMAIL"));
            String caste = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CASTE"));
            String fname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("FNAME"));
            String mname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MNAME"));
            String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ADDRESS"));
            String contact = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CONTACT"));

            arrayList.add(name);
            arrayList.add(enrollment);
            arrayList.add(year);
            arrayList.add(dob);
            arrayList.add(email);
            arrayList.add(caste);
            arrayList.add(fname);
            arrayList.add(mname);
            arrayList.add(address);
            arrayList.add(contact);

        }
        return arrayList;
    }
```

It's not returning anything.I'm not able to fetch the data from the database. The array size is zero:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
```

at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:25

Please help me out guys. I'm new to this stuff.

Comment: That's a different scenario there @ShreeKrishna.. I am not able to retrieve the data from the database..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not `while(cursor.isAfterLast())` it should be `while(!cursor.isAfterLast())` Or simply do

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks man @Shree Krishna that worked! :-) just did that `cursor.moveToNext`

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

Cursor cursor = database.query("STUDENT", ALL_COLUMN_NAME, null, null, null, null, null);
if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
{
    cursor.close();
    return null;
}
cursor.moveToFirst();
while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    for (int column = 0; column < cursor.getColumnCount(); column ++) {
        arrayList.add(cursor.getString(column));    
    }
}
return arrayList;
```